# Using XPath contains with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm quite familiar with XPath in PHP, and wanted to use it within JavaScript with the end goal of making an extension to help me with something.

I have the following XPath which works and tested in the dev tools on Chrome:

```
//div[contains(@data-bt,'rank')]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work with **querySelectorAll**. Yet the following does:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[data-bt]")
```

I've also noticed that using `//` on the XPath seems to throw an error saying its not a valid selector.

Comment: The latter is a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) not XPATH. `.querySelectorAll` requires CSS selectors.

Comment: thank you, seems i was getting confused between xpaths and querySelectors. Also that you for working my question better :)

Comment: Beware of the [XY trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284546)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading about `querySelector`. I found the following does the same as the XPath I was trying to achieve.

```js
x = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-bt*="rank"]');

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    json_str = x[i].getAttribute('data-bt');
    data = JSON.parse(json_str);
    console.log(data.id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not exactly sure what it is that you are trying to accomplish, here is a snippet that might help.

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bt*="rank"]');
const identifiers = Array.from(nodeList).map(node =>
  ({
    id: node.dataset.id,
    bt: node.dataset.bt
  }));

console.log(identifiers);
```

```html
<div data-id="1" data-bt="rank1">Rank 1</div>
<div data-id="2" data-bt="rank2">Rank 2</div>
<div data-id="3" data-bt="rank3">Rank 3</div>
```